# Object sent from C++/CLI to C#?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, c++-cli

My friend build an application ( console app) in C++/CLI.

I'm programming in C#.

Ive build for him some DLL in C# which does some calculations based on params that **he** send.

My function (inside my C# dll) looks like this :

```cs
bool LongCalc(dynamic obj)
{
    ...
}
```

(again , the obj needs to be sent from his c++/cli to my c# dll).

my question :

If he creates an object in his **cpp** like :

```
cppObj 
{
    prop1 , prop2 , prop...n
}
```

would I be able to read his obj in my **c#** as :

```
obj.prop1

obj.prop2 .... ?
```

*what should he or me need to do in order for me to work with his obj ?*

Comment: You need to specific whether this is C++ CLR or standard C++

Comment: @PeteKirkham sorry you right. its cpp CLR.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If he's using your C# DLL from his C++ application then I'm guessing he's using managed C++. If that's the case then it'd make sense for him to define his C++ class as a [managed C++ class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++/CLI) so that you'll be able to invoke methods against it.

Answer (score 0):

The answer highly depends on how your friend is consuming your C# dll.

If he's using plain C++ and consuming your .NET assembly through .NET COM Interop, then I don't think a `dynamic` parameter will be supported for a plain C++ class like `CppObj` from your example, becuase there is no way to know how to invoke the object's methods during run time.

In order for this to work with a `dynamic` parameter in the C# side, the C++ class will probably have to be a COM object and implement `IDispatch`, so that the CLR will have the ability to dynamically invoke methods on the C++ object.

I'm not 100% sure that `dynamic` actually supports `IDispatch` in COM Interop, but I see no theoretical reason why it shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, `dynamic` supports COM. It was a godsend for COM interop.